# What happens when a capacitor gets a current over its rated current?

Tags: capacitor, current

An example capacitor is rated 400 V and 5 A.
What would happen to it, if it was given a continuous current at e.g. 50 A?

Would there be Thermal Runaway as would happen with a battery that is fed a continuous current that is too high?

Comment: What 5A current are you referring to? Link to datasheet? Do you mean the ripple current spec?

Comment: It depends on the specific capacitor and the duration of the event. Not all capacitors are equal in this respect so, I'd consider specifying a particular capacitor if I were you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current limit for a capacitor (AC, obviously you cannot have long duration DC) is generally dictated by its ESR (equivalent series resistance) and heating. Prolonged excess current will heat it to too high a temperature. Usually the first to fail will be the dielectric. In a plastic capacitor, it could soften and mechanically fail to keep the plates apart, which would result in a short circuit. In an electrolytic capacitor, with the 10x abuse (100x power) that you are considering, the electrolyte would boil, and the resulting steam cause it to vent or explode.

If you exceed the rated current by a smaller margin, running hotter would cause the life of an electrolytic to be severely reduced, due to increased rate of loss of electrolyte.